# Is it necessary to write these headers in C?

Tags: c, header-files

I want a list of Header files in `C` which are not necessary to use them.

**Example:**

```
scanf(), printf(),.... etc. //can be use without stdio.h
getch()...etc.   //can be used without conio.h
```

Is is necessary to write these headers(stdio.h, conio.h) while I use these(above) methods?

Comment: The docs for pretty much every library function, or API, or syscall would state which .h file you need to include for it.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. Is there a particular reason that you want to avoid including the standard headers when you use functions they define?

Comment: @Cody Gray:Just I want to know its effect on each case.

Answer (score 4):

Using functions without prototypes is deprecated by the current standard, C99, and will probably be removed in the next version. And this is for a very good reason. Such usage is much error prone and leads to hard to track faults. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the current C language standard, function declarations (but not prototypes) are mandatory, and prototypes have always been mandatory for variadic functions like `printf`. However, you are not required to include the headers; you're free to declare/prototype the functions yourself as long as you have the required types available. For example, with `printf`, you could do:

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
printf("%d\n", 1);
```

But with `snprintf`, you would need at least `stddef.h` to get `size_t`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
int snprintf(char *, size_t, const char *, ...);
```

And with non-variadic functions, a non-prototype declaration is valid:

```
int atoi();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your compiler.

For GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/builtins.def?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use any C function without a header.  The header contains the prototypes for these functions making it possible to warn about wrong type or number of parameters.

So yes you can do without these headers.

But **no** you shouldn't do this.

But normally you don't write these header, these are provided by the build environment.

Another thing since these checks are only warnings in C you should switch on these warnings and treat them like errors.  Otherwise you are in for a very bad C experience.

In gcc you should always run with options `-W -Wall`and avoid all warnings these give.

An BTW these are not methods but functions.

**Addendum:** since you are gonna treat all warnings as errors you might turn on `-Werror` which turns all warnings into error just enforcing this.

Personally I'm not using this option but have the discipline to clean out all warnings in the end.  This makes it possible to ignore the warnings for a while and usually do a clean up before I commit to version control.

But certainly for groups it makes sense to enforce this with `-Werror` e.g. in test scripts run before allowing commits.

Comment: No `-Werror`? :) <== smiley for 15 characters :) <== smiley for reason for 1st smiley :)

Comment: Yeah, forgot about because I'm doing this by personal discipline ... added it now